# What should our documentation contain?

Tags: discussion

What should we list on the [`About`](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/about) page under "ask about" and "don't ask about".

Also, what else should go on the [`What topics can I ask about here?`](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [`What types of questions should I avoid asking?`](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) pages?

The initial work on this is essentially already done for us in the Area 51 proposal, but we'll want to flush these out further as well.